# SCP Jenkins Plugin does not copy selectively

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, scp

I want to copy only specific files in a directory to remote server using Jenkins SCP Plugin.

I have folder structure /X/Y/...Under Y, I need only the files a b c among a b c d e f. Is this possible...?

Of course, to copy all files all you need is X/Y/**. But what about copying selectively.
I was reading somewhere that this is a kind of bug in the plugin.

I have string parameter, $FILES=x,y,z highlighted in "BUILD WITH PARAMETERS"

SCP Configuration:

Source: some/path/$FILES (relative to $WORKSPACE)
Destination: /var/lib/some/path

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to say `X/Y/a; X/Y/b; X/Y/c`
Also remember that these files have to be under the job's `${WORKSPACE}`

Alternatively, you can have another build step in-between that copies only the files that you want into a staging folder, and then supplying the staging folder to SCP plugin

***Edit after OP clarification:***

Your `$FILES` variable contains `x,y,z` When you supply this as *Source* to SCP plugin, it becomes:

```
some/path/x,y,z
```

Or if we break this one item per line:

```
some/path/x
y
z
```

The first item is valid, the next two are not complete paths, therefore are not found.

Several ways to fix it (chose either **one**):

### Full path in parameter variable.

- Under your `FILES` **string parameter**, list the full path, like:
  `some/path/x, some/path/y, some/path/z`
- Under **SCP Source**, use only `$FILES`

*pros:* quick and stable.
*cons:* looks ugly with long paths.

### Wildcard path in parameter variables.

- Under your `FILES` **string parameter**, list the global wildcard path (files will be found under any directory), like:
  `**/x, **/y, **/z`
- Under **SCP Source**, use only `$FILES`

*pros:* quick and looks *better* than long paths.
*cons:* **only** works if files `x`, `y` and `z` are unique in your whole workspace. If there is `$WORKSPACE/x` and `$WORKSPACE/some/path/x`, one will end up overwriting the other.

### Prepare `MYFILES` variable and inject it.

- You need an **Execute Shell** build step added. In there write the following:
  `mypath=some/path/
  echo MYFILES=${mypath}${files//,/,$mypath} > myfiles.props`
- Then add **[Inject environment variables](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin)** build step (get the plugin in the link). Under *Properties File Path*, specify `myfiles.props`.
- Under **SCP Source**, use only `$MYFILES` (note you are reading modified and injected variable, not the original `$FILES`)

*pros:* looks good in UI, proper and further customizable.
*cons:* more build steps to maintain in configuration.

**p.s.**
In all these cases, a multi select **[Extended Choice Parameter](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Extended+Choice+Parameter+plugin)** will probably look better than a string parameter.

Comment: In jenkins I defined a parameter $FILES which has values of the files to be copied (15 files out of 30). I have been trying to use this parameter $FILES in the SCP Plugin Ant task. Not getting a way through it. Using a parameter should be a convenient way because, today I want to copy only 15, tomorrow may be 16. So I just have to add that additional file name to $FILES

Comment: `$FILES` is your parameter defined on Job configuration under **This build is parameterized**? Or is that an environment variable defined elsewhere in the script? If the first is true, you should be able to use `$FILES` in your SCP plugin. Post the configuration (edit original question, don't post in comments here) of your SCP plugin, and post your console log where it is failing